# async def and coroutines, what's the link

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm trying to wrap my head around the new asyncio functionnalities which appeared in Python3.

I started from a simple worker example found on stackoverflow, modified a bit :

```
import asyncio, random

q = asyncio.Queue()

@asyncio.coroutine
def produce(name):
    while True:
        value = random.random()
        yield from q.put(value)
        print("Produced by {0}".format(name))
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1.0 + random.random())

@asyncio.coroutine
def consume(name):
    while True:
        value = yield from q.get()
        print("Consumed by {0} ({1})".format(name, q.qsize()))
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1.2 + random.random())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(produce('X'))
loop.create_task(produce('Y'))
loop.create_task(consume('A'))
loop.create_task(consume('B'))
loop.run_forever()
```

I mostly understand how it works (except perhaps for the `yield from asyncio.sleep()`... Is it a placeholder for a delegated, but blocking function ? Where does it yield to ?)

But, above all, how could I transform this example to use the new fancy `async def` and `await` keywords ? And what would be the gain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def f(arg)
```

with

```
async def f(arg)
```

and `yield from` with `await` in your code.

Also read [PEP 412](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) about `async with` and `async for`.

Answer (score 3):

This article is what I found to be the most helpful.

http://www.snarky.ca/how-the-heck-does-async-await-work-in-python-3-5